# How to display the value of nullable field in the database in the ASP.NET TextBox control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ and I am struggling now with displaying the value (whether there is a value or it is Null) of a number columns in my Entity model. These values should be displayed on ASP.NET TextBox control. 
The fields are declared as Nullable columns, however, I am still getting this error (or exception)

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

every time I try to display the value in a TextBox

Here's my code:

```
textBox1.Text = result.FirstOrDefault().Name.ToString();
```

**So how can I display the null values in the TextBox control?**

Comment: if result of quarry equal to null then if commend will run otherwise if data is come the u able to show data

Comment: plz send your code  then it possible to give u full solution of your problem

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the linq query returns `null`, you get an exception if you try to access `Name`

```
var res = result.FirstOrDefault();
textBox1.Text = res != null ? res.Name.ToString() : null;
```

Also, if name is already a string, you do not need to call `ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

The exception comes form null.ToString().

```
var res = result.FirstOrDefault();
textBox1.Text = res != null ? res.Name.ToString() : "-";
```

You can do it like this, you can leave it only with null like @FlatEric wrote.